# How to add an invisible view into LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-viewgroup

Is that possible to add an invisible view/view group into LinearLayout which will not affect sizes of other children of the layout. Here are details.

I have a simple LinearLayout with a Toolbar, RecyclerView and a TextView at the bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/list_background" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="@string/empty"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now I want to add a view or view group which is actually visible but not affect sizes and locations of other widgets and hide it with .offsetTopAndBottom method.
After that to use ViewDragHelper class to show the view based on some gestures. Actually the behavior is similar to BottomSheetBehavior but without CoordinatorLayout involved.
The only problem is that I cannot figure out how to add the view into LinearLayout.

Comment: <FrameLayout><LinearLayout><childviews.../></LinearLayout><YourView/></FrameLayout>

Comment: You can use `Space` layout https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html

Comment: To wrap LinearLayout with FrameLayout should work out. in this case YourView will be measured but laid out at 0, 0 position. thx pskink! so as it a comment not an answer can I vote for that somehow?

Answer (score 0):

To make a View not only invisible, but also not take up any space, thereby not interfering with layout behaviors like wrap_content or layout_weight you can set the Views visibility to **gone** either in XML using **android_visibility="gone"** or in code using **yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE)**

Comment: Did I get clear that after yourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) LinearLayout will invoke onMeasure() and yourView's dimensions will affect sizes and locations of other widgets?

Comment: Yes, you got that right! When you set the visibility to "gone" instead of "invisible" the dimensions of the view are 0, while when using "invisible" the views dimensions will stay the same, although the view can't be seen.
**I just double checked. View.setVisibility(xy) does trigger linearlayouts onMeasure()**

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/list_background" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:text="@string/empty"/>
     <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:hint="@string/loginEmailHint"
        android:id="@+id/loginEmail"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>


Here a an example
```